# como puedo corregir el error de editar el registro en BD sqlite3 con python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite3

```
def editar(pelicula, id_pelicula):
conexion = ConexionDB #establecemos la conexion a BD
#creamos el objeto en sql
sql = f"""UPDATE peliculas
SET nombre = '{pelicula.nombre}',
    duracion = '{pelicula.duracion}',
    genero = '{pelicula.genero}'
WHERE id_pelicula = {id_pelicula}"""


try:
        conexion.cursor.execute(sql)
        conexion.cerrar()

except:
    titulo = 'Edicion de Datos'
    mensaje = 'No se puedo editar el registro'
    messagebox.showerror(titulo, mensaje)
```

def editar_datos(self):
try:
self.id_pelicula = self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())['text']
self.nombre_pelicula = self.tabla.item(
self.tabla.selection())['values'][0]
self.duracion_pelicula = self.tabla.item(
self.tabla.selection())['values'][1]
self.genero_pelicula = self.tabla.item(
self.tabla.selection())['values'][2]

```
        #luego de recuperar los datos de la tabla, vamos a habilitar los campos
        self.habilitar_campos() #habilito los campos

        #lo enviamos a los entries para que se muestren
        self.entry_nombre.insert(0, self.nombre_pelicula)
        self.entry_duracion.insert(0, self.duracion_pelicula)
        self.entry_genero.insert(0, self.genero_pelicula)


    except:
        titulo = 'Edicion de Datos'
        mensaje = 'No ha seleccionado ningun registro'
        messagebox.showerror(titulo, mensaje)
```

Comment: Tu código no es reproducible, y no explicas cual sería el error. No se me ocurre como ayudarte sin poder conocer el error de algún modo. Por favor lee [como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [como crear un ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Además, recomiendo que añadas la etiqueta python para que tu pregunta llegue a más gente.

Comment: Gracias Dante. Ala momento  de realizar la modificacion en el dato, lo hace pero agrega un nujevo registro. el campo que se estaba editando no sufre ninguna alteracion, sino que agrega un nuevo registro con el cambio.